# LINQ equivalent of WHERE IN clause

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have 3 tables `Purchase`, `PurchaseBill`, and `PurchasePayment`.

`Purchase` has one-to-many relationship with `PurchaseBill`
`PurchaseBill` has one-to-many relationship with `PurchasePayment`

I'm looking for a Linq (fluent) equivalent of this SQL Query

```
SELECT COUNT('') FROM PurchasePayment
WHERE PurchaseBillId IN (
   SELECT PurchaseBillId FROM PurchaseBill WHERE PurchaseId = @PurchaseId
)
```

Basically I want to know if any `PurchasePayment` record exist for certain `@PurchaseId`

Currently I'm using

```
                var bills = _context.PurchaseBill.Where(a => a.PurchaseId == obj.Id);

                foreach (var bill in bills)
                {
                    var hasPayment = _context.PurchasePayment.Any(a => a.PurchaseBillId == bill.Id);

                    if (hasPayment)
                        ctx.AddFailure("Cannot modify paid Purchase.");
                }
```

I tried
`var hasPayment = _context.PurchasePayment.Any(w => bills.Contains(w.PurchaseBillId));`
but it's not working. Is it possible to do it without looping in Linq?

Comment: Used in this way, `IN` is in fact a join between `PurchasePayment` and `PurchaseBill `. You should (configure and) use a navigation property between the two classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Gert; you ought to have a `PurchaseBill` class with an `ICollection<PurchasePayment> PurchasePayments` property (linking onto the multiple payments) and an `int PurchaseId` property (linking back to a single purchase) and be able to do something like:

```
var hasPayment = context.PurchaseBills.Any(
  pb => pb.PurchaseId == obj.Id && pb.PurchasePayments.Any()
);
```

"Is there any purchasebill with PurchaseId blahblah and any PurchasePayment?"

Or, if you plan to do something with each bill, and its payments, something like:

```
var bills = context.PurchaseBills.Include(pb => pb.PurchasePayments);

foreach(var pb in bills){

  if(pb.PurchasePayments.Any()){
    //do something with the bill and its purchase here
  }
}
```

But don't do this if all you're going to do is add a message to an error list; it's a lot of data to download for the sake of looking through and finding one bill record that might have a payment record - that is better done by the first recommendation that asks the DB for a simple boolean - "is there any payment anywhere for this purchaseId?"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
var hasPayment = _context.PurchasePayment.Where(x => _context.PurchaseBill.Where(a => a.PurchaseId == obj.Id).Any(y => y.PurchaseBillId == x.PurchaseBillId)).Any();
```

I tried an example here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/uTs6pd

Answer (score 0):

You can implement something like this:

```
var PurchaseId=1;
var result = _context.PurchasePayment.Where(x=>_context.PurchaseBill.Where(y=>y.PurchaseId==PurchaseId).Select(y=>y.PurchaseBillId).ToList().Contains(x.PurchaseBillId)).Count();
```